# How many core Drupal 7 functions are there?

Tags: 7

How many functions are in Drupal 7 or how would I find out?

Update:
I am thinking of memorizing all of them and think it would be good to know before hand what kind of goal I need to shoot for.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to close this question as not constructive. As the [FAQ] says, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." Which actual problem would require you to know how many functions Drupal 7 defines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 4520 PHP functions listed in Drupal 7 core.

Source: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/functions/7

50 items per page, 90 full pages + 1 page of 20 = 4520.

Comment: Out of interest why do you need to know this?

Comment: I am thinking of memorizing all of them and think it would be good to know before hand what kind of goal I need to shoot for. Thanks for telling me the way you calculated the answer too!

Comment: @Clive you beat me to it :P

Comment: Are you Rain man?